# How to get a custom type instead of Integer when using Collectors.summingInt?

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collectors

I am currently creating a `Map<String, Map<LocalDate, Integer>>` like this, where the `Integer` represents seconds:

```
Map<String, Map<LocalDate, Integer>> map = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x.getProject(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                x -> x.getDate(),
                Collectors.summingInt(t -> t.getDuration().toSecondOfDay())
            )
        ));
```

How could I instead create a `Map<String, Map<LocalDate, Duration>>`?

Comment: I notice that [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) does not have a `toSecondOfDay()` method. Are you using another type or is this mistake for `getSeconds()`?

Comment: @DidierL I use LocalTime to save duration, It looks prettier in DBMS.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to misuse a Java type for the sake of database representation. You should use a specific converter instead, to map to the DB type of your choice – if the default conversion does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change that `Integer` from `Collectors.summingInt` to a `Duration`, you simply need to replace that `Collector` with:

```
Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.summingInt(t -> t.getDuration().toSecondOfDay()),
    Duration::ofSeconds
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using an actual `Duration` for `getDuration()` (instead of `LocalTime`), you could also sum directly the `Duration`'s as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<LocalDate, Duration>> map = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyObject::getProject,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                MyObject::getDate,
                Collectors.mapping(MyObject::getDuration,
                        Collectors.reducing(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus))
        )
));
```

With the advantage that it also sums the nanoseconds, and could be generalized to other types as well.

Note however that it creates many intermediate `Duration` instances which could have an impact on the performance.